# Is Expo Pedometer supported on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-developers-console

I'm setting up a Pedometer app in React Native using Expo, testing the code on my real Samsung s10 device.

[I am using the Expo Pedometer documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/pedometer/)

However, when I use the `Pedometer.getStepCountAsync` method, I get returned an error "Getting step count for date range is not supported on Android yet."

I am trying to make a pedometer app that reads users steps, and then puts them into some visuals for the user but I can't get the steps data.

My code is below: it reaches the error => line and returns the error mentioned above. :(

I've enabled the Fitness API in my Google Developer Console and am 99% sure I have the right credentials; as I have used the Google Login successfully in the same app.

```
const end = new Date();
    const start = new Date();
    start.setDate(end.getDate() - 1);
    Pedometer.getStepCountAsync(start, end).then(
      result => {
        this.setState({ pastStepCount: result.steps });

      },
      error => {
        this.setState({
          pastStepCount: "Could not get stepCount: " + error
        });
      }
    );
```

I guess the expected result is that I get the user's steps from the past day in the result but instead I get the error that it is not supported on android.

Answer (score 1):

I did something nasty as a workaround but it worked I added expo 33 as a legacy npm dependency and use only the pedometer module from there because currently they didn't implemented the pedometer functionality on android on the new Expo unimodules

package.json

```
"expo": "^35.0.0",
 "expo-legacy": "npm:expo@33.0.0",
```

And use it like this

`import {Pedometer} from 'expo-legacy'`

Surprisingly compiled and only increased 200kb the apk size

Comment: Is there any better solutions at the moment?

Comment: I don't think so, at this point with the new Expo SDK, you can use the Bare Workflow to be able to add any Podometer you like

Comment: hey there can you pls tell ware to add this because I am a react native beginner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using Core Motion (iOS) or Google Fit (Android) to get the user's step count.
Any Android phone running on a 4.4 (KitKat) operating system or later will connect with Google Fit.

[Pedometer unable to query steps, documentation unclear/contradictory.](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4895)

Comment: plz have you any tutorial step bu step to connect expo with Google Fit, I tried many solution and plug-in but can't get pedometer working in android devices, and thx