# Expo Pedometer "Getting step count for date range is not supported on Android yet"

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-oauth, expo, pedometer

When i updated expo SDK from 32 to 35, I get returned an error "Getting step count for date range is not supported on Android yet."

My code and google fit api configuration are clean. I know, because my app at google play store and it is working. Please help me, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with Expo 35, where they forgot to reimplement Android function for getStepCountAsync...  I guess we'll have to wait for Expo 36 to use it again! 
In the meantime, 
[an option to use Pedometer with Expo 35 is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846394/is-expo-pedometer-supported-on-android)

Comment: expo 41 released .. still getting step count is not supported at android :(